# The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(LongPressEndDetails)?'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set up button, which has green color, when on long press and red, when it is released (back to initial state)

onLong press is working fine, but when I added onLongPress end I got error:

> The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(LongPressEndDetails)?'.

Here is my code snippet:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: () => setState(() {}),
  onLongPressEnd: () => setState(() {}),
),
```

Comment: change `onLongpress` with  `onLongpressDown`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onLongPressEnd` provides `LongPressEndDetails` on callback, you need to add param,

```dart
onLongPressEnd: (details) {
  
},
```

or ignore like

```dart
onLongPressEnd: (_) {
  
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did this, but in simulator I do not see that on long press button color changes to red back. What can be wrong? onLongPressEnd: (_) => {
        selectedColor = Colors.red,
        textonpressed = Text('Take a deep breath and press button for 10 seconds', 
        style: GoogleFonts.abhayaLibre(
        textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        height: 1.5,
        letterSpacing: 0.8,
        color: Colors.black
        ), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
        },

Comment: make sure to put the variable declaration outside the build method and you didnt use `selectedColor`. if you still fails feel free to ask new question with your best effort + minimal snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: The `onLongPressEnd` callback expects a function that also accepts the event details (`LongPressEndDetails`).

So your code should look like:

```dart
   ...
   onLongPressEnd: (details) => ...
   ...
```

If you are not interested in the event details you can ignore them like this:

```dart
   onLongPressEnd: (_) => ...
```